# GridGain download from Maven Repository blocked by Avast AV

Tags: antivirus, gridgain

I can't pull GridGain binaries from Maven repository, since Avast AV blocks GridUtils class as suspected "Agent-CWF" trojan. Tried all 6.* versions with the same result. I'm hesitant to ignore it without confirmation that there is nothing wrong with it and it will also create problems across organization since other team members would probably run into the same problem. Anybody else ran into this? Running Avast 10.2 on OS X 10.10.1.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the same issue. This is innocent and can be ignored. The fact that some bytes in GridUtils class match some trojan sequence is a pure coincidence.